# Outlook - Sychronise contacts from exchange

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, exchange, contacts

At work the exchange server has details of all employees in the system.

Then there is the Contacts folder in Outlook.

I can populate this with all staff, but, I want to synchronise it against all staff (occasionally) removing people who in are in my local contacts, but not in the Exchange server (leavers) and importing changes/updates/new staff from the exchange server.

However, I also have some personal contacts (family members etc) locally that I want to exclude from that.

This is to enable synching to my smartphone better.

Any suggestions?

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand properly what you want to achieve, but here goes.. You have your personal Contacts folder in Outlook. That's the one that gets sync'ed with your smartphone.

Then you can have other other contacts folders (coming from Public Folders, SharePoint etc) that show up in Outlook only, and you can drag and drop from/to your personal Contacts, those contacts that you wish to share/add to your Outlook and sync to your phone. Right?

So you want to filter the contacts that get synchronized between your phone and Outlook? You can set filters (Right-click folder, Properties, Synchronization) on the Contacts folder to achieve some kind of filtering of contacts to your server, will that solve your problem?
Otherwise, just leave all contacts in the Outlook Contacts folder synched with your phone, I have several hundred contacts on my phone, and I never have any sync problems. For the people in your organisation, you have the ability to search the Global Address List (GAL) from the phone, so you don't have to manage all those contacts manually.

Did I understand your request correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an iPhone and you are syncing via Activesync, in Outlook create a new contact "folder" underneath "Contacts" called "Personal". It will show up on the phone as a subfolder and you can keep those seperate. It is a nice solution to the Personal contacts.

Other phones may also support this.

Sorry, no suggestions for a simple solution to your syncing to your GAL other than to suggest you check if your phone allows you to use LDAP to query the GAL from exchange directly. That would eliminate the need to sync the company contact list with your local list. You could manually do the contacts from your team or very frequently contacted people, but the LDAP query would be good enough for most.